# Printing word document changes default printer

Tags: powershell

I have this code that dynamically changes a word document. But when I try to print it changes the default printer

```
$objWord = New-Object -ComObject word.application
$objWord.Visible = $False   #False
$Path = "$root\UNB\TMP\$archivo.docx"
$objDoc = $objWord.Documents.Open("$Path")
         
$objWord.ActivePrinter = "IMP_TIQUETE"

$objDoc.PrintOut()
while ($objWord.BackgroundPrintingStatus -ne 0) {
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}
  
$objDoc.Close([ref]0, [ref]$null, [ref]$null) # Delete the file
$objWord.Quit()


Remove-Item $root\UNB\TMP\$archivo.docx -Force
```

How I can print the document in a particular printer without changing the default printer settings?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I think windows 10 automatically makes the most recent printer the default one.

Comment: No it doesn't.. Also in working on win 11 and it doesn't change as you describe.

Comment: Uncheck "let windows manage my default printer" https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/set-a-default-printer-in-windows-e10cf8b8-e596-b102-bf84-c41022b5036f

Answer (score 0):

First capture the default printer using

```
$defaultPrinter = Get-CimInstance -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer WHERE Default=$true"
```

Then do your stuff with Word and after quitting Word reset the previous default printer with

```
$null = Invoke-CimMethod -InputObject $defaultPrinter -MethodName SetDefaultPrinter
```

P.S. Cleanup the used COM objects after use so they won't linger in memory:

```
$objWord.Quit()
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objDoc)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objWord)
$null = [System.GC]::Collect()
$null = [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```